# How can i render the functionality components that already has information to another component in react?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React.js.
I want to render this exact same layout that is chosen to `ChartType` page when I move `ChartType` page.

This is my `Layout` page code.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Panel from "./Panel";
import PanelTwo from "./PanelTwo";
import PanelFive from "./PanelFive";
import styled from "styled-components";

export default function Layout() {
  const [showPanel, setShowPanel] = useState(false);
  const [showPanel2, setShowPanel2] = useState(false);
  const [showPanel5, setShowPanel5] = useState(false);

  const handleOnClick = () => {
    setShowPanel(true);
    setShowPanel2(false);
    setShowPanel3(false);
    setShowPanel4(false);
    setShowPanel5(false);
  };

  const handleOnClick2 = () => {
    setShowPanel2(true);
    setShowPanel(false);
    setShowPanel3(false);
    setShowPanel4(false);
    setShowPanel5(false);
  };
  const handleOnClick5 = () => {
    setShowPanel5(true);
    setShowPanel(false);
    setShowPanel2(false);
    setShowPanel3(false);
    setShowPanel4(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Main>
        <div onClick={handleOnClick}>
          <h1>Panel (1+3)</h1>
        </div>
        <div onClick={handleOnClick2}>
          <h1>Panel (2+2) </h1>
        </div>

    

        <div onClick={handleOnClick5}>
          <h1>Panel (3+1)</h1>
        </div>
      </Main>
      {showPanel && <Panel />}
      {showPanel2 && <PanelTwo />}
      {showPanel3 && <PanelThree />}
      {showPanel4 && <PanelFour />}
      {showPanel5 && <PanelFive />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

and this is `ChartType` page code

```
import React from "react";
import BarChart from "./ChartTypes/BarChart";
import ChartMenu from "./ChartMenu";
import Layout from "../LayOut/Layout";

const ChartType = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <ChartMenu />
      <Layout />
    </>
  );
};

export default ChartType;
```

I tried to put `Layout` component on `ChartType` component
but it's not what I want it to be so I want to render this page only the one that I choose in `Layout` page to `ChartType` page.

[image: this is layout page and I chose one layout]

and this is chart type page

[image]

How can I render it and what skills should I learn to do it?
If my explanation is unclear tell me please.

Comment: Hello, are you wanting to duplicate the panel state/callbacks/panel components from `Layout` to `ChartType` component, or is something else like selecting a layout from `Layout` and using it in `ChartType`? Or something else?

Comment: Really Good to see u Sir ! , Im just wanting selecting a layout from Layout and using it in ChartType !

Comment: See [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) for learning how to move the state to a common ancestor and passing props to children to (1) update the state and/or (2) read the state. Move the state into a common parent component, pass the setters to `Layout` and the state values to `ChartType` for rendering.

Comment: Yeah Sir ! I'll learn it and i will try to figure it out ! I really appreciate you taking the time for answering my question !